# trigger for update

Tags: sql-server, triggers

i have trigger in sqlserver on table (tabs)

```
Create TRIGGER Trig_TabsUp
on Tabs
For UPDATE 
AS 
insert into tabs_Update select * from deleted
```

the table `tabs_update` the same as tabs but the identity field in tabs is not identity in `tabs_update` it just int. It gives me this error

> the row values updateed or deleted either don't make the row unique or the alter multiple rows 2 rows

i tried to put an identity field to the table Tabs_Update but still the same error

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` to your trigger definition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have a Primary Key or unique constraint on the ID field. This is problem on the second time you update the same record. `Sp_help Tabs_update` will tell you what they are.

You were right to make the ID field just and int. But you should probably add a Update Date Time field and make the primary key a composite of the ID and update Date time.

Also doing select * is almost always considered a bad idea. Your trigger will break if you add a new field and forget to add the update table. It will also break if you change the order of the fields.

Comment: Having the trigger break if the base table definition changes but the audit table doesn't is not a bad thing here IMO. It is better than the alternative where the base and audit table definitions get out of synch.

Comment: @Martin Regrettably it may not break right away. In one case I experienced it took some time after the base table changed before the errors started occurring. Some hypothesitzed that the trigger didn't recompile right away. Becasue of this it took some time before the problem was resolved. This was much worse than some data not being audited. But I can see it both ways

Comment: Was a view involved? You might have needed to run `sp_refreshview`